# Object Property Undefined in Javascript/Redux

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, properties

I used redux local storage to store the following:

```
{"id":1,"first_name":"","last_name":"", “hobbies”:{}}
```

This is how their login info was stored:

```
 localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response.data.user));
```

This is how I'm retreiving the data:

```
  var user_info = localStorage.getItem(("token"));
```

So user_info is able to show the following:

```
  {"id":1,"first_name":"","last_name”:"", “hobbies”:{}, "created_at":"2016-08-03 18:03:23","updated_at":"2016-08-03 18:03:23"}
```

NOW I want to access `id` but when I do the following:

```
    var id = JSON.stringify(user_info["id"]);    
    OR 
    var id = JSON.stringify(user_info.id);
```

I keep getting the following error. What is the proper way of accessing a property like "id"?

```
   undefined
```

Comment: you have to use `JSON.parse` otherwise it's just a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you need to use `JSON.parse()`instead of `JSON.stringify()` to parse a JSON object, then after it's parsed you can access its properties.

```js
var json = '{"id":1,"first_name":"","last_name":"", "hobbies":{}, "created_at":"2016-08-03 18:03:23","updated_at":"2016-08-03 18:03:23"}';
var id = JSON.parse(json).id;
document.write(id);
```